# Unit test on angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Currently I'm working on Angular unit test with jasmine framework. Still couldn't figure out how to add unit test to below code snippets.

Any ideas on that ?

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. Are you trying to launch test right after OnInit or are you trying to test user interaction with unit testing? Because for both, this is not how unit tests are supposed to work.

Unit tests are about testing separate units from your code once your whole application is running, so you test what is in memory, not what your user does (like scrolling to top) and then check what is in memory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure, It affects to unit test coverage, That's the main concern.